# Derivative of y = $(5x)^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

How can I solve this using logarithms?I thought I could break it into $\ln(\sin(x))\cdot(\ln(5)+\ln(x))$?
However it seems that it breaks into $\ln(\sin(x))\cdot\ln(5x)$.

Why can I not break up the $\ln(5x)$ into $\ln(5)+\ln(x)$?

Comment: Break it as $e^{\ln 5x \cdot \sin x}$

Comment: $\log(5\,x^{\sin(x)}) = \log(5)+\sin(x)\, \log(x)$

Comment: Or did you mean $(5x)^{\sin(x)}$?  Parentheses matter.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes that it what it is. Updating the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking logarithms, $\ln(y) = \ln((5x)^{\sin(x)}) = \sin(x) \ln(5 x)$ because (at least when $a > 0$) $\ln(a^b) = b \ln(a)$.  And then $\ln(5 x) = \ln(5) + \ln(x)$, so
$$ \ln(y) = \sin(x) \ln(5) + \sin(x) \ln(x) $$